# Doctrine Memcached: Clear cache after save record

Tags: caching, symfony1, doctrine, memcached

Does Doctrine 1.* clearing cache after save record?

It seems like it doesn't. Can I do it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. You should clear your cache manually each time you saved an object.

As describe [in the doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/08-Advanced-Doctrine-Usage#chapter_08_sub_deleting_cache), the best way is to do it using event, specially, `postSave` event:

```
// lib/model/doctrine/User.class.php

class User extends BaseUser
{
  // ...

  public function postSave($event)
  {
    $cacheDriver = $this->getTable()->getAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE);
    $cacheDriver->deleteByPrefix('users_');
  }
}
```

You can also built a custom class to manage the cache clear ([as describe here](http://ada.mbecker.cc/2012/02/13/doctrine-1.2-and-memcached-woes/)):

```
<?php
class myCache{

    public static function clearRegexMatches($regex){
       Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()
            ->getAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE)
            ->deleteByRegex($regex);
    }

    public static function clearOne($name){
        Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()
            ->getAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE)
            ->delete($name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the Doctrine_Manager class located?